# Did Buck Rogers Starfighters Have Retracting Wings?

Tags: canon, buck-rogers, toys

One of my favorite shows as a kid was `Buck Rogers`, and I always liked the design of the Earth starfighter in the show.

I also had a small toy of the starfighter, made by Corgi, shown here:[image: Buck Rogers Earth Starfighter]

On the toy, there was a little peg on the bottom that made the wings retract into the body. 
This got me wondering where that came from. I do not remember them ever retracting in the show. Is this something they just decided to do on the toys, or was there some canon justification (the comics maybe?) for manufacturing them this way?

I wasn't entirely sure whether this would be on-topic, but after reading the [on-topic help](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I figured it would fall under "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The retractable wings aren't canon. They appear to be a feature on all of the [Corgi](http://www.chezbois.com/corgi/small_scale/Model_5258.htm) Buck Rogers Starfighter models.

As you can see from the concept art below (by the famous Ralph McQuarrie) the wings are fixed;
[image: Buck Rogers Fighter 1]
[image: Buck Rogers Fighter 2]

You can also see the welded joins in the close up pictures from the TV series;

[image: Buck Rogers Fighter 3]
[image]

Comment: Huh, didn't know McQuarrie did BR; that's cool. That is just the TV show though, no? Was the show the only appearance of this general design? He wasn't doing an update on an established design or anything, was he?

Comment: He seems to have *originally* designed a range of ships for BSG. These were some that didn't get used but did ultimately get recycled into Buck Rogers. As far as I'm aware these are original concept art.